# scala akka: have actor remember something it should eventually reply to?

Tags: scala, actor, akka

in akka suppose there is a linear chain of actors such that each actor receives a message from upstream, sends its own message downstream and waits for a reply, and then sends a message back upstream. how can the actor remember the handle of the upstream actor when it has to reply to that actor later?

for example:

```
A sends message to B (b ! "msg1")
B sends message to C (c ! "msg2")
C replies to B (self.reply ! "msg3")
B replies to A <--- ???
```

basically, how can B remember a handle for A? doing self.reply at this point would refer to C, since C sent the current message to B.

Answer (score 6):

Must actor *B* change the reply message between *C* and *A* ?

1. If not, actor *B* should use `B forward "msg"` instead of `B ! "msg"`. That will preserve the sender information. When *C* use reply, the answer is automatically sent to *A* without passing by B:

   `A sends message to B (b ! "msg")`

   `B forward the message to C (c forward "msg")`

   `C replies to A (self.reply ! "msg3")`
2. If yes, get the sender `ActorRef` and pass it along the message sender reference.

For example, using a simple tuple:

```
A sends message to B (b ! "msg1")
B sends message to C, with the sender reference (c ! ("msg2",self.sender) )
C replies to B adding the reference it received (self.reply ! ("msg3",ref) )
B replies to A ( ref ! "msg4" )
```

Here I used a Tuple, but if you have a longer chain, pass a `List[ActorRef]`. When going forward, you prepend senders refs. And when going back, you reply to the list head and pass the list tail along the reply.

**Edit:** Taking Victor comment into account.

Comment: FYI: Doesn't matter if B changes the message or not, forward will work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. However, the caveat still applies if B must change the reply to A.